Pipewire utterly broken; Only output is Dummy Output
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, Desktop, X11 windowing, gnome, 64-bit,
I've tried every single fix to this I could find, but nothing ever worked for me. So I finally cracked and made an account to try and get an answer for this.
I updated my video drivers and suddenly my pipewire stopped working on reboot.
Output of
pipewire
is
[E][00423.993063] mod.protocol-native | [module-protocol-:  660 lock_socket()] server 0x5fe5b2803c80: unable to lock lockfile '/run/user/1000/pipewire-0.lock': Resource temporarily unavailable (maybe another daemon is running) [E][00423.993354] pw.conf      | [          conf.c:  560 load_module()] 0x5fe5b27e9150: could not load mandatory module "libpipewire-module-protocol-native": Resource temporarily unavailable [E][00423.993585] default      | [      pipewire.c:  123 main()] failed to create context: Resource temporarily unavailable 
Tried to delete the mentioned file so that pipewire could regenerate it, but this only caused pipewire to freeze after regenerating it.
Please help!

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details for us to help you with. You've also not said exactly what you did; as PipeWire has been automatically setup for the five most recent releases; so if you've mucked it up, what exactly you did maybe required to help you fix it on your unstated Ubuntu product & release.

apologies. I've added the ubuntu version. is this sufficient or is there anything I need to add?

You've not added a release (22.04) but haven't given product details (Server? Desktop? flavor? etc), however Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is rather old and did NOT come with PipeWire setup by default as it wasn't available when 22.04 when using the GA kernel (what was released with 22.04)  The five releases using PipeWire (by default) are Ubuntu 22.10 thru 24.10.  https://ubuntu.com/blog/whats-new-in-ubuntu-desktop-22-10-kinetic-kudu

Was not aware 22.04 was old considering it was released within the last 2 years... I will update to the newest edition, see if that helps. Also adding more info...

Ubuntu's releases in the last two years are 23.04, 23.10, 24.04 & 24.10.  Ubuntu 22.04 was released in 2022-April which is why its 22.04; which is more than 2 years 6 months ago !

my god, how time flies... that's most probably the cause. I'm updating immediately. Can't believe I've even HAD this system for that long. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Pipewire is not broken, but your installation, obviously. You might consider setting up Ubuntu 24 from scratch
